# Arduino Uno R3 (with Atmega 16U2) and macOS 10.11 not working

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-nano, mac-os, atmega16u2

So,
I have the newest Arduino IDE (1.8.5) installed and the newest release of Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.21.

My OS: macOS 10.11.6.
Usually I only use Nano's china clones with an CH340 USB-Serial chip, I have installed the wch driver and it worked fine !
My Nano's have the newest bootloader (Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.21).

And now the really annoying problem:
I recently ordered Elegoo Uno R3 boards, they have the original 16U2 chip for USB-Serial, no FTDI and no CH340 it's a Atmega 16U2.
And of course nothing works..
When I connect the Elegoo Uno to the mac (over the USB cable), it will show up in the system report - > USB as Arduino, but the IDE won't found it.
Sometimes it will be found by the IDE, but when I click upload (the Blink sketch) it print following:

```
    avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:01:35
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Users/USERNAME/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/USERNAME/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem5D21
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : Arduino
         Description     : Arduino
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
         Hardware Version: 3
         Firmware Version: 4.444305
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
         Vtarget         : 322122183.2 V
         Varef           : 49804.8 V
         Oscillator      : 548.816 Hz
         SCK period      : 3495249366.4 us

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

So it receives the board information, but then the programmer does not respond, then he responds again and then not, a back and forth.
I have already made it by repeatedly clicking that the program has been uploaded.

Now the possible sources of error:

1. USB cable
2. Atmega328
3. Atmega16U2
4. My thought: something with the auto reset

Sidenote: I also update the 328 and 16U2(over DFU and USBasp) bootloader with an USBasp, no success (the bootloaders have been uploaded successfully, but I still can't upload a sketch)

Now the things I tried:

1. Other USB cable -> no success
2. Upload bootloader to the 328 -> success, program it via an TTL adapter over RX TX -> success, the led start blinking.
3. Upload bootloader to the 16U2 -> success, but simultaneously not an success, because the bootloader was uploaded successfully, but I still can't upload a sketch.
4. I read read read over 5 hours now, and the only helpful articles were:

[Same problem as me, he has/had an mac with 10.11.06](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19180/)

He did it with an update of the USB drivers via MultiBeast (hackintosh driver installer) I also try it with no success (I also know that their is now driver for the 16U2, because normally there are built in CDC/ACM drivers, exception windows.)

..................

[Arduino IDE serial ports not working on EL Capitan OSX](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/3928)

A big Github thread, with no real solution.

..................

[The 80% solution](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=221900.15)

That gave me the idea to test it in a virtual windows machine and surprise surprise it worked, it uploaded without any errors (that I did not figure it out sooner, my fault).

So now I know that the usb cable, the 328, the 16U2 are fully working and nothing is damaged, the only thing that is not working is my mac.
Sometimes the UNO's are not recognized. 
Sometimes the sketch is only uploaded to 90 percent, then the board doesn't respond.
The Nano's are fully woking, I thought maybe the CH340 driver for the NANO's make problems ?

So because of that my mac have problems with the UNO boards.

Honestly after that, I have no idea, I just want it to work.

Comment: A hackintosh is not a supported platform. Either Linux or Windows on a PC or OS X on a Mac. A frankensteinian combination of the two, well, it's anyone's guess what may work and what won't.

Comment: @Majenko Sorry this is absolute nonsense.

Comment: Using an operating system designed for Mac hardware on a pc (yes, the CPU is the same, but so what?) is asking for trouble. There are no guarantees that hardware drivers will function right. That includes things like the USB subsystem.

Comment: Do you come here to discuss or help?

Comment: If you had an Arduino problem then sure, we'd help. You have already proved that your Arduino is fine and that the problem is with running osx on a pc. We don't support that configuration. We know nothing about that kind of thing. Osx on a Mac, sure, you have a chance of support, since many here use a Mac. A real Mac. (Poor fools). I know of no one else that uses osx on a pc.

Comment: Ok i updated my question with "macintosh", because i think you don't understand that also the ones who have a "real mac" could help me very well, because many have the same issue and maybe someone fixed it.

Comment: From what I can see it's either problems with el crapitan (it's known as that for a reason) or hackintosh USB drivers. The Arduino is just a class-compliant CDC/ACM device. No drivers needed, no magic to get it working. Unless the OS is buggy as hell or you're running it on unsupported hardware.

Comment: No magic, hmm.. why so many people have the problem ?
[Github Blog](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/3928)
With a OS that is stable as hell.
I will wait on answers, that give me more information, so that I can explore new solutions paths.

Comment: "Stable as hell..."...  (howls of derisive laughter...)

Comment: It sounds to me like the whole USB subsystem in El Crapitan is completely borked. For example, it's not just CDC/ACM that suffers: *"Some users report that audio output devices attached via USB will spontaneously disconnect, with audio output reverting to internal speakers. "*

Comment: Here's one nice review quote: *"While the Apple faithful want users to focus on the benefits of upgrading to El Capitan, what I'm seeing is the rockiest, most buggy OS X release I can ever remember, and the first time since OS X has been available for download that I've not upgraded all my systems on day one."*

Comment: My suggestion: Either upgrade or downgrade. Like I said: it's called "El Crapitan" for a reason.

Comment: No, I don't have such problems, my machine is rather stable.
It is only the port problem.
Oh, and to the "It's the Hackintosh's fault", whenI run the virtual machine, it is working just fine ,the mac even redirects the port to the vm.
It's also listed in the system report, it's not a real hackintosh problem.
It's a problem in macOS 10.11, 
that's what i know.
And I think that a few people fixes this problem very well !

Comment: No, people with a real mac fix a problem that sounds *similar* to yours. You have an OS with known USB faults running on foreign hardware using third party USB drivers. Your problem is reasonably unique to you, because very few other people use the same combination as you. Which is why the fixes that work for other people don't work for you.